Libreria Pywhatkit Python
tengo un problema con la librería pywhatkit, los mensajes se quedan como draft y nunca se llegan a mandar, en teoría la imagen se copia al portapapeles y se debería pegar cuando se abre whatsapp pero nunca se pega por lo tanto no se envía tampoco, alguien que trabaje con esta librería o sepa la solución?
import pywhatkit as kit
import pyautogui as pg
import time
import os

# Configura la información
phone_number = '' # Número de teléfono en formato internacional(por seguridad no esta el numero)
message = 'Hola, este es un mensaje automatizado con imagen.'
image_path = 'C:/Users/Tkm-Marketing/Desktop/Vida Digital/Para subir/Regreso a Clases Tecmarket.png' # Ruta al archivo de imagen

# Envía el mensaje usando pywhatkit
kit.sendwhatmsg(phone_number, message, time.hour, time.minute + 2) # Enviar el mensaje en 2 minutos

# Espera para permitir que el mensaje se envíe
time.sleep(120) # Ajusta el tiempo de espera según sea necesario

# Abre la interfaz de WhatsApp Web
pg.hotkey('ctrl', 't') # Abre una nueva pestaña en el navegador
pg.typewrite('https://web.whatsapp.com\n', interval=0.05) # Escribe la URL y presiona Enter
time.sleep(10) # Espera a que WhatsApp Web se cargue

# Encuentra y selecciona el chat con el número
pg.click(x=200, y=200) # Ajusta la posición del clic según sea necesario
time.sleep(5)

# Haz clic en el botón de adjuntar
pg.click(x=1230, y=964) # Ajusta la posición del clic según sea necesario
time.sleep(5)

# Adjunta la imagen
pg.write(image_path, interval=0.05) # Escribe la ruta del archivo de imagen
pg.press('enter') # Presiona Enter para seleccionar el archivo
time.sleep(5)

# Envía la imagen
pg.click(x=1215, y=964) # Ajusta la posición del clic según sea necesario
pg.press('enter') # Presiona Enter para enviar

print("Mensaje e imagen enviados.")

# Cierra la pestaña de WhatsApp Web
pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'w') # Cierra la pestaña actual

